# RemoteClass issue between Flex and Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript

In flex I have a class 'MapDrawingPoint', in one of my mxml files I create ArrayCollection and fill it with MapDrawingPoint instances.

```
var mapDrawingPoints : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
...
mapDrawingPoints.addItem(MapDrawingPoint);
```

Then I do a remote call to my Java backend with the list of objects, in debug mode I can see that I'm coming in my Java method but the expected ArrayList as input is a flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection with the exact amount of elements but not of type MapDrawingPoint but of type flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject.

On the Java class MapDrawingPoint I did nothing special, I just made sure I have the right properties there. Same for the AS class I created, it has the same properties as my Java class but I added the bindable- and remoteclass tag:

```
package model {
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="com.mycompany.model.MapDrawingPoint")]
public class MapDrawingPoint {
...
```

I'm using BlazeDS for the remoting on a backend server running Tomcat with Spring (and also spring-flex) configured...

Does anyone of you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is in line:

```
mapDrawingPoints.addItem(MapDrawingPoint);
```

where you're adding instances of `Class` (classes itself) but not instances of `MapDrawingPoint`.